# How to check whether email is paypal email or not using php?

Tags: php, paypal

I want to check whether email is paypal email or not I have gone through GetVerifiedStatus api but is there any other to check whether supplied email exists on paypal or not any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can connect to the mailserver, and ask whether the mail address exists. See for instance: https://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email Some mail servers might not support this feature.

Comment: Actually I wanted to check whether they have account on paypal or not.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself.

Comment: You got it now?